# Identifying an Actor using an ActorSelection

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

I'm writing an `Actor` that should watch another `Actor`; let's call the latter one the *target*. My `Actor` should stop itself once its target is stopped. For this target I only have an `ActorSelection`. To watch it, I obviously need an `ActorRef`, so I figured I should send the `ActorSelection` an `Identify` message; when it replies back with `ActorIdentity` I would have its `ActorRef`. So far so good, but I can't get it to work.

Here's the spec:

```
// Arrange
val probe = TestProbe()
val target = TestProbe().ref
val sut = system.actorOf(MyActor.props(system.actorSelection(target.path)), "watch-target")
probe watch sut

// Act
target ! PoisonPill

// Assert
probe.expectTerminated(sut)
```

And the implementation (an `FSM`, details skipped):

```
log.debug("Asking target selection {} to identify itself; messageId={}", selection.toString(), messageId)
selection ! Identify(messageId)

when(Waiting) {
  case Event(ActorIdentity(`messageId`, Some(ref)), Queue(q)) =>
    log.info("Received identity for remote target: {}", ref)
    context.watch(ref)
    goto(NextState) using TargetFound(ref)
  case Event(ActorIdentity(`messageId`, None), Queue(q)) =>
    log.error("Could not find requested target {}", selection.toString())
    stop()
}

initialize()
```

Now, when I run my test, it is green because the system under test is indeed stopped. But the problem is it stops itself because it can't find its target using the aforementioned steps. The log file says:

> Asking target selection ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://default/), Path(/system/testProbe-3)] to identify itself; messageId=871823258
>
> Could not find requested target ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://default/), Path(/system/testProbe-3)]

Am I missing something obvious here? Maybe a `TestProbe` should not reveal its real identity? I even tried by instantiating a dummy `Actor` as *target* but the results are the same. Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is actually very simple: the test runs so fast that before `MyActor` sends the `Identify` message to the `selection`, the `Actor` behind the selection has already received its `PoisonPill` and thus is killed.

Adding a little `Thread.sleep()` before sending that `PoisonPill` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The target actor is getting terminated before the identify request is being made.  This is because [Akka only guarantees order when sending messages between a given pair of actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#message-delivery-reliability).

If you add a `thread.sleep` above the following line, the identify request should succeed.

```
Thread.sleep(100)
// Act
target ! PoisonPill
```

Note that there may be better ways to code the test - sleeping the thread is not ideal.

Your watching actor should also handle the `Terminated` message of the target actor, as described [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Lifecycle_Monitoring_aka_DeathWatch).